# convergence of a series (involving factorial, power and sum)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ consider the positive number
$$\alpha_n := \frac{2^{-n}}{n!}\,\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^n}{k!} \,.$$

Is the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha_n$ convergent or divergent?

Comment: WolframAlpha says divergence, I'll try to come back with a proof

Comment: Uhm.. a plot with Mathematica seems to say convrgent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything is non-negative, hence we can freely rearrange our sums:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-n}}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k^n}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{(k/2)^n}{n!}\\
&\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} e^{k/2}\\
&= e^{\sqrt{e}}\\
&< \infty.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Well, you can "freely" rearrange...as long as the sums exists, i.e. as long as the series converge.

Comment: That's the point: if the sum is infinite in any arrangement, it's infinite in all arrangements. This of course depends on the fact that all terms are non-negative [it'd work the same with all terms non-positive, of course].

Comment: @DonAntonio Since everything is nonnegative, it is not necessary to check that the series is convergent.

Comment: @Daniel I discovered your comment too late...

Comment: Oh, I see your point @DanielFischer. Thanks +1